# How to make streamlit dropdown menu interactive?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a dataframe as below:

```
    sender                  date         keyword        value
0   zdf                     2021-05-19   motor          2.0
1   bund_der                2021-07-13   motor          4.0
2   bund_der                2021-07-16   stator         5.0
3   infos                   2021-07-25   stator         2.0
4   infos                   2021-07-29   motor          1.0
```

I am trying to make dashboard using **streamlit**. There will be two drop down menu; one to select from column "sender" another one for the column "keyword". And the output will be a line chart where the date will be in the x-axis and value will be in y-axis.

I have used the following code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.read_csv('all_data_streamlit.csv')


def plot_count_keyword(df):       
    kw_count_sender_selectbox = [st.sidebar.selectbox(
        "Senders", df["sender"].unique())] # Dropdown box to select sender
    kw_count_keyword_selectbox = [st.sidebar.selectbox(
        "Keywords", df["Keywords"].unique())] # Dropdown box to select the keyword

    
    df_kw_count_selected_sender = df[df['sender'].isin(kw_count_sender_selectbox)]
    df_kw_count_selected_keyword = df_kw_count_selected_sender[df_kw_count_selected_sender['keyword'].isin(kw_count_keyword_selectbox)] 

    df_kw_count_selected_keyword.groupby(['mail_date']).sum().plot()
    plt.show()    
    st.pyplot(fig=plt)
plot_count_keyword(df)
```

The problem is, it only shows the output for the first element of each selectbox. I "thought", selecting different elements in the selectbox will recalculate everythng and update the plot.

I think, here it is not doing so. It is just fixed to the first plot. Is there anything to trigger the calculation when changing the selectbox selection? Or, Do I have to clarify the output in the code for each cases(e.g. if kw_count_sender_selectbox  == 'infos': thend DO This)?

Comment: Can you add a graph/image/something (in your post) to show what you'd like the output to look like? Do you mean the output plot isn't updating when you change the keyword selection? Not sure your goal, but if you want to keep multiple keyword selections, you store them in a dictionary